# Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel, cannot show my foreign key data

Tags: database, laravel, foreach, model

please help, i'm trying to show the data from my database, but the one is showing is the "id" of the table (id Kelas). i want to show the "kelas" and "jurusan_kelas" in my "Murids" table from "Kelas" table. this table have 1 to many relation.

this is the error `Trying to get property 'jurusan_kelas' of non-object (View: D:\new xampp\htdocs\sekolah\resources\views\murid\indexMurid.blade.php) http://sekolah.test/murid`

this is my "murid" model

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'nis',
        'nama_murid',
        'kelas',
        'gender',
        'tanggal_lahir',
        'alamat',
        'nomor_telp',
    ];
    public function kelas(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Kelas::class, 'kelas','id');
    }
```

this is my "kelas" model

```
protected $fillable = [
        'kelas',
        'jurusan_kelas',
        'wali_kelas',
    ];

    public function murids(){
        return $this->hasMany(Murid::class, 'kelas','id');
    }
```

this the migration for "murid"

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('murids', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('nis')->unique();
            $table->string('nama_murid');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->date('tanggal_lahir');
            $table->string('alamat');
            $table->bigInteger('nomor_telp');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('murids');
    }
```

this is migration for "kelas"

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('kelas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('kelas');
            $table->string('jurusan_kelas');
            $table->string('wali_kelas')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('kelas');
    }
```

this is add "kelas" to murid table migration

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('murids', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('kelas')->index()->after('nama_murid');

            $table->foreign('kelas')->references('id')->on('kelas')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('murids', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->dropColumn('kelas');
        });
    }
```

this is my "index.blade"

```
 @foreach ($murids as $murid)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $murid->nis }} </a></td>
                                <td>{{ $murid->nama_murid }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $murid->kelas->jurusan_kelas}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $murid->gender }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $murid->tanggal_lahir }} </a></td>
                                <td>{{ $murid->alamat }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $murid->nomor_telp }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                    <form action="{{ route('murid.destroy', $murid) }}" method="post">
                                        @csrf
                                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <form action="{{ route('murid.edit', $murid) }}">
                                        @csrf
                                        {{-- <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="EDIT"> --}}
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Edit</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                                
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

[this is my table to display the data from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPKko.png)

[this is the data that i want to show on the red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqPRS.png)

my problem is displaying another data from the another table, i want to get the data not the "id" of the table (fk)

Comment: add your other model code along with migration files.

Comment: edited, sorry if my english bad or i did something wrong, i'm new in this laravel and coding thing

Comment: Could you show the database records you expect to find back? Maybe the data is wrong/unattached.

Comment: *Trying to get property of non-object* is a good place to start your debugging. Are you returning a single record? Or a collection?

Comment: @FullStackOfPancakes if that is a collection,  then the error will be something like : _Property [jurusan_kelas] does not exist on this collection instance_

Comment: @RobBiermann edited, this is what you mean? i'm sorry if it's not what u mean i'm really new in this laravel and database thing. laravel version that i use is 8

Comment: @FullStackOfPancakes i didn't get it the difference between single or collection, i already added some image, i hope it can help you understanding what i mean, i'm sorry if i don't understand

Comment: check your database..somehow some data may be got deleted..code seems ok